# Webhooks for Oracle Cloud Infrastructure - container registry

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Looking for a solution to this use case

1. Docker image is pushed to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure - container registry (OCIR)
2. Jenkins has a webhook on the OCIR and Jenkins pipeline gets triggered as a new image is available in OCIR

How is it possible to have a webhook or some kind of mechanish for letting Jenkins know there is a new push to OCIR?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post walks you thru how to set up a continuous pipeline that may be able to be used in full or in part to accomplish this

https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/build-a-continuous-integration-pipeline-using-github,-docker-and-jenkins-on-oracle-cloud-infrastucture

Answer (score 0):

We can listen to the OCI container registry events via Service Connector. You can configure Service Connector to invoke your custom functions on a specific event 'Container Image - Upload' under service name 'Registry'.

You can find a sample illustration below to perform some custom tasks during an image upload to OCI Container Registry.

Ref: https://github.com/RahulMR42/oci-devops-deploy-on-imageupload